# Unable to Return [BindingList[RandomType]] from ScriptProperty

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a complex class that dynamically adds members to itself based on a file loaded via `Import-Clixml`.

Boiling the class down to the problematic part leaves us with this *(Take note of the commented line used to prove success up to that point)*:

```
class TestClass {
    [hashtable]$_data = @{}
    [void]DefineData([object]$data) {
        $this._data['Data'] = $data
        $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'ScriptProperty' -Value {
            #$this._data['Data'].GetType() | Out-Host
            return $this._data['Data']
        }
    }
}
```

In the following code, there are 4 statements for assigning a value to `$OriginalValue`. Leave 3 of these statements commented and uncomment the one you want to try.  When executed, the code should result in `$ReturnValue` containing the same value as `$OriginalValue`, but in the case of assigning `$OriginalValue` an instance of `[BindingList[RandomType]]`, `$ReturnValue` is `$null`.

```
$ClassVar = [TestClass]::new()

$OriginalValue = [System.ComponentModel.BindingList[string]]::new()
#$OriginalValue = @{}
#$OriginalValue = [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'Value' }
#$OriginalValue = "Test String"

$OriginalValue.GetType()
$ClassVar.DefineData($OriginalValue)

$ReturnValue = $ClassVar.ScriptProperty
$ReturnValue.GetType()
```

Yes, I can hack my way around the problem by storing instances of `[BindingList[RandomType]]` in a `[hashtable]`, but could someone explain what is going on, or even better yet, how to fix the code for all data types?

Comment: Your output is getting enumerated, just change to `return , $this._data['Data']` problem should be solved

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, thank you!  Make that an Answer and I'll except it!

Comment: You could also change to `$this.PSObject.Properties.Add([psscriptproperty]::new('ScriptProperty', { , $this._data['Data'] }))` much easier to read (biased)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, thank you.  Didn't realize you could add a script property that way.  Where is the docs on that?  I would like to do Add-Member's -SecondValue for Get/Set.

Comment: Mmm the docs are the SDK docs I guess, i.e.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfocollection-1.add?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-psmemberinfocollection-1-add(-0)

Comment: for getter setter you can do `[psscriptproperty]::new('foo', { 'im getter' }, { 'im setter' })` so no difference really. `Add-Member` uses this behind the scenes.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, tried the getter/setter version and it worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments, the problem is not the `BindingList` but the output from your [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) being enumerated. Since your `BindingList` has no elements when you call `.DefineData($OriginalValue)` then enumerating a list with no elements via `.ScriptProperty` results in null value:

```bash
(& { [System.ComponentModel.BindingList[string]]::new() }).GetType()

# Errors with:
# InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

A simple workaround is to wrap the output in a single element array before outputting, for this you can use the [comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-).

```bash
(& { , [System.ComponentModel.BindingList[string]]::new() }).GetType()

# Output type is preserved and the wrapping array is lost due to enumeration
```

So, your `class` method could look as follows considering the `hashtable` property is not needed:

```bash
class TestClass {
    [void] DefineData([object] $data) {
        $this.PSObject.Properties.Add(
            [psscriptproperty]::new(
                'ScriptProperty',
                { , $data }.GetNewClosure()
            )
        )
    }
}
```